# To link a value in an .M-file to a .MAT-file

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a program in MATLAB to solve integrals, and I have my function in a .M-file. Now I wonder how I can write a program in the .MAT-file that lets the user set a value that exists in the both files. The .M-file looks like this:

```
function fh = f(y)
fh = 62.5.*(b-y).*(40-20.*exp(-(0.01.*y).*(0.01.*y)));
```

and as you can see, the function depends on two variables, y and b. I want the user to set b. I tried putting b = input('Type in the value of b: ') in the .M-file but for some reason the user would then have to put in the same value four times.
Can I ask for the value of b in the .MAT-file?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, m-files store *code* (i.e. functions), while MAT-files store *data* (i.e. variables). You can save workspace variables to a MAT-file using the function [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) and load them into a workspace from a file using the function [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html). If you have a user choose a value for `b`, then save it to a MAT-file (`'b_value.mat'`, for example), you can simply load the value from the MAT-file inside your m-file function like so:

```
function fh = f(y)
  load('b_value.mat','b');
  fh = 62.5.*(b-y).*(40-20.*exp(-(0.01.*y).*(0.01.*y)));
```

However, this is not a very good way to handle the larger problem I think you are having. It requires that you hardcode the name of the MAT-file in your function `f`, plus it will give you an error if the file doesn't exist or if `b` isn't present in the file.

Let's address what I think the larger underlying problem is, and how to better approach a solution...

You mention that you are solving integrals, and that probably means you are performing [numerical integration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsgprfe-1.html) using one or more of the [various built-in integration functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5872.html#f16-6472), such as [QUAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html). As you've noticed, using these functions requires you to supply a function for the integrand which accepts a *single* vector argument and returns a *single* vector argument.

In your case, you have other additional parameters you want to pass to the function, which is complicated by the fact that the integration functions only accept integrand functions with a single input argument. There is actually a link in the documentation for [QUAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html) (and the other integration functions) that shows you a couple of ways you can [parameterize the integrand function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsgprpq-5.html) without adding extra input arguments by using either [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) or [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html).

As an example, I'll show you how you can do this by writing `f` as an anonymous function instead of an m-file function. First you would have the user choose the parameter `b`, then you would construct your anonymous function as follows:

```
b = input('Type in the value of b: ');
f = @(y) 62.5.*(b-y).*(40-20.*exp(-(0.01.*y).^2));
```

Note that the value of `b` used by the anonymous function will be fixed at what it was at the time that the function was created. If `b` is later changed, you would need to re-make your anonymous function so that it uses the new value.

And here's an example of how to use `f` in a call to [QUAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html):

```
q = quad(f,lowerLimit,upperLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your m file declare b as a global

```
function fh = f(y) 
    global b
    fh = 62.5.(b-y).(40-20.*exp(-(0.01.y).(0.01.*y)));
```

This allows the variable to be accessed from another file without having to create another function to set the value of b.  You could also add b to the arguments of your fh function.